# Could the browser download remaining resource while JavaScript is running

Tags: browser

I studied the loading behavior of Chrome/FireFox/Safari, all of them will be blocked while inline JavaScript running. Any impacts if do a rough sanning for remaining unparsed document and launch new sub resource downloading task?

Below is my testing page:

```
<script>
i=0;
while(i<100000)
{
   i = i+1;
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = i;
}  
 </script>  
 <img src="http://images.csdn.net/20130516/HK.jpg" />
```

Looking forward to learn detail of why browser block until the inline script is performed finished?

Answer (score 0):

These days it's considered best to put all your Javascript includes and code just before you close the `<body>` tag, so that the browser can get on with downloading all the stuff in parallel that it can (e.g. images, css) in the mean time.